# Cómo imprimir ticket automaticamente desde el hosting con PHP sin mostrar dialogos de impresion?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html5, print

estoy haciendo una pagina web para un restaurant, donde por ejemplo un usuario, desde su casa, trabajo, etc, puede hacer su pedido en la pagina y luego de concretar la compra con sus datos bancarios el pedido debe registrarse en la base de datos(esto ya esta hecho y funcionando bien), pero automáticamente en el restaurant debe imprimirse en una impresora para Ticket el pedido que ha hecho ese usuario.

Datos: Esta pagina web tiene a su vez un sistema de administración(hecho en php) donde los trabajadores del restaurant pueden ver todos los pedidos realizados por los clientes, ver cuanto se ha vendido durante el dia y también pueden cambiar cierto contenido de la pagina web como la moneda que se usa, los platillos que se ofertan, entre otras cosas. 
La pagina web solo esta disponible en el horario que abre el restaurant.
En el restaurant, durante el horario de trabajo siempre se mantiene abierto el sistema que administra la web.

Cómo puedo hacer para que una vez el cliente termine de hacer su pedido, este se imprima en la impresora que esta en el restaurant? Es posible? Cómo podria hacerlo con PHP o JS?
Alguna libreria que puedan recomendarme que me ayude con esto?

Comment: Para un problema puedes encontrar muchas soluciones, pero lo primero que se me ocurre con php es: ejecutar comandos usando shell_exec(), por ende, puedes generar una archivo a imprimir en X directorio cpm php y luego vía comando imprimir ese archivo.

Comment: es decir de esta forma, el comando se ejecutaria en segundo plano y mandaria a imprimir en la impresora del restaurant? Una de las opciones en las que habia pensado era en una tarea CRON que se ejecutara cada 1 minuto, y detectara si habia alguna orden en cola para impresión, de ser verdadero mandarla a imprimir, pero no estaba seguro si eso podria ser factible. Sin embargo tu sugerencia se ve más interesante.

Comment: existen muchas posibilidades, como bien mencionas, una alternativa es también crear otro programa que se encargue de imprimir los pedidos. para esto me imagino que este programa toma los pedidos desde base de datos y  se encarga de imprimir los registros de la tabla pedidos si es que existen o no han sido impresos.

puede ser con un cron o con un request desde el mismo PHP, etc.

Answer (score 0):

yo logre realizar lo que indicas comunicando el sistema desde el hosting con una apliacion en un servidor xampp local (es decir en la PC del punto de venta) el cual a su vez es quien se conecta localmente a la impresora termica mediante la libreria mike42.

Es importante tener en cuenta que para lograr la comunicación, en el navegador es necesario desactivar el "block insecure private network requests" ya que por defeto lo tiene activado

chrome://flags/#block-insecure-private-network-requests